# Get user machine's IP address when a website is configured with Apache Varnish in front of Tomcat

Tags: apache, jakarta-ee, tomcat6, varnish

Currently, I am running a website which is running on Tomcat which has Apache in front and varnish for caching. Tomcat is running on port `8080` and port `81` is used as varnish back end. I need to implement a feature for which I need to know the IP address of the client's machine visiting the website. I've tried to access the IP address by the header `X-FORWARDED-FOR`.

When the website is accessed from port 81 (i.e. http://mywebsite.com:81/) I can get the IP address of the client's machine but unfortunately when accessing through default port 80 (i.e. http://mywebsite.com/) it's returning the localhost IP address (127.0.0.1). Can anyone suggest what can be the worked around to get the user's real IP address from port 80 as well?

Comment: Did you configure apache to include the x-forwarded-for header ?

Comment: you mean from apache2.conf or configure from varnish vcl file?I didn't do any of these.

Comment: both. you may also need to configure tomcat as well.  just as a quick example: I tend to have nginx on port 80, which can proxy back to a mix of web app servers on the same machine or within the network ( and could be something like: apache, uwsgi/python , php-fcgi, etc ).  I have to configure nginx on the 'public' ip to strip out any spoofed headers and pass back x-real-ip. then the other servers have configs/middleware that move x-real-ip/x-forwarded-for into remote_addr.

Comment: but in my case nginx is not running in front of apache/varnish.In my case varnish is on port 80,apache is on port 80 and then tomcat is on port 8080

Comment: I've checked the apache log and found that the referrer for port 80 is being shown as 127.0.0.1 which means that when varnish is submitting the request to apache the client ip is being treated as localhost ip.So,is there any workaround to make varnish submit the referrer as the real ip of the host machine instead of localhost ip?

Comment: well i said in my example ;)   you'll need to check the varnish and apache config to see what is going on in both.  both are configurable for this.  varnish might be passing in the real ip on another header variable ( or not passing it in at all ).

Answer (score 0):

Your setup, if I understood correctly, is as follows:

Varnish (port 80) -> Apache (port 81) -> Tomcat (port 8080)

And you would like the actual remote IP to show up as `REMOTE_ADDR` on the Tomcat server.

Varnish appends `X-Forwarded-For` header by default, so that's already sorted. To get Apache to pass the actual remote IP to Tomcat, you should install [reverse proxy add forward module for Apache (mod_rpaf)](http://stderr.net/apache/rpaf/). mod_rpaf does exactly what you're looking for. The appropriate config for Apache would be:

```
<IfModule !rpaf_module>
    LoadModule rpaf_module modules/mod_rpaf-2.0.so
</IfModule>

<IfModule rpaf_module>
    RPAFenable On
    RPAFsethostname On
    RPAFproxy_ips 127.0.0.1
    RPAFheader X-Forwarded-For
</IfModule>
```

After enabling the module Tomcat should see the correct `REMOTE_ADDR` header as well as the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` header.